# Pipe to Get-Mailbox in Echange Online

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

Is using `ForEach-Object` mandatory in that case or can I pipe the variable to `Get-Mailbox` directly?

```
$importuser = Import-Csv -Path C:\mymailbox.csv -OutVariable string
$importuser | ForEach-Object {
  get-mailbox -identity $_.Name|Select-Object primarysmtpaddress,whenMailboxCreated
} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Set-Content -Path "exportwhithedate"
```

Comment: i don't understand your point. [*blush*] would you please try to restate your Question? ///// also, the `Import-Csv` cmdlet does not have any output ... and that means the `-OutVariable` parameter won't do anything. ///// also also, you never try to use the `-OutVariable` result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `-Identity` takes the pipeline input (according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-mailbox?view=exchange-ps) and my tests) you can pipe it:

```
$importUser.name | Get-Mailbox # And so on
```